# Circular image in a circular progress bar [CANVAS]

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I have attempted to create a circular progress bar and a circular image using canvas separately but I tried putting them together, and the result is not what I wished for. What I am hoping for is, if  45% of the progress bar is complete, then the complete part should be in the pinkish color and the rest of the stroke must be black(the 55% remaining), also the image must be circular and there must be a text in the middle of the image.

I'm fairly new to canvases and I would very much appreciate any places I could learn canvases or any similar technologies associated with web design.

Also I do note that there are questions related to circular progress bars and circular images using canvases, but none of them have the both of these topics combined. As a beginner at this canvas technology, I am not capable of extracting the necessary information from the other topics.

Any help is appreciated!

Cheers!

[EDIT]: I must point out that I do not want any answers suggesting me to use libraries, this is a learning experience so I do not want to use libraries.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>T</title>
</head>

<body>

    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="200"></canvas>
    <script>
        var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var al = 50;
        var start = 4.72;
        var cw = context.canvas.width / 2;
        var ch = context.canvas.height / 2;
        var diff;

        function progressBar() {
            diff = (al / 100) * Math.PI * 2;
            context.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 200);



            context.fillStyle = '#000';
            context.strokeStyle = '#ff2626';
            context.textAlign = 'center';
            context.lineWidth = 10;
            context.font = '10pt Verdana';
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(cw, ch, 55, start, diff + start, false);
            context.closePath()
            context.stroke();
            context.fillText(al + '%', cw + 2, ch + 6);

            var img = new Image();

            img.onload = function () {
                context.beginPath();
                context.arc(cw, ch, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                context.clip(); 
                context.closePath();
                context.strokeStyle = '#ff2626';
                context.lineWidth = 10;

                context.stroke()
                context.fillText(al + '%', cw + 2, ch + 6);

                context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            };

            img.src =
                "http://www.antiquiet.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/Free-Trapper_Remasters_The-Kills-467x311.jpg";


        }
        progressBar()
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In order to get the rest of the circle black you need to draw an other black circle underneath. Also: do not close the path. This is giving you ugly corners at less than 50%
2. I added `context.fillStyle` for the text and I'm aligning the text around the center
3. although I'm seeing your image in codepen I can't see it in SO. Please check it in your computer. The image *is* circular. Since the text was underneath the image I've added `context.globalCompositeOperation='destination-over';` to move the text over the image.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var al = 30;
var start = 4.72;
var cw = canvas.width / 2;
var ch = canvas.height / 2;
var diff;

function progressBar() {
  diff = al / 100 * Math.PI * 2;
  context.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 200);

  context.fillStyle = "#000";

  context.textAlign = "center";
  context.lineWidth = 10;

  // the black circle
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(cw, ch, 55, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  context.stroke();
  // the pink arc
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(cw, ch, 55, start, diff + start, false);
  context.strokeStyle = "#ff2626";
  //context.closePath()
  context.stroke();

  context.font = "20px Verdana";
  // aligning the text around the given point
  context.textAlign = "center";
  context.textBaseline = "middle";
  context.fillStyle = "#ff2626";
  context.fillText(al + "%", cw, ch);

  var img = new Image();

  img.onload = function() {
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(cw, ch, 55, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context.clip();
    context.closePath();

    context.globalCompositeOperation='destination-over';
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
     
    context.fillText(al + "%", cw / 2, ch - 20);
  };

  img.src =
    "http://www.antiquiet.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/Free-Trapper_Remasters_The-Kills-467x311.jpg";
}
progressBar();
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid;}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works, and the comments are helpful too! Are there any resources you would recommend for me to learn about canvas?

Comment: For an introduction (very basic) try this: [HTML5 Canvas Element Tutorial](https://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-element/) or this book [Head First HTML5 Programming: Building Web Apps with JavaScript](https://www.amazon.com/Head-First-HTML5-Programming-JavaScript/dp/1449390544/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1545055137&sr=8-1&keywords=HTML5+head+first).

Comment: Try this other book if you are already into canvas coding: [Foundation HTML5 Animation with JavaScript](https://www.amazon.com/Foundation-HTML5-Animation-JavaScript-Lamberta/dp/1430236655/ref=as_sl_pc_tf_til?tag=html5anim-20&linkCode=w00&linkId=&creativeASIN=1430236655)

Comment: Thanks a bunch enxaneta!